# UIImageView is resizing

Tags: iphone

I have an issue with uiimageviews resizing at run time.  On one view I have more than a dozen uiimageviews contained within a uiscrollview.  The images are assigned at design time.  The uiimageview's are all the same size.  The mode is set to Aspect Fill for all uiimageviews.  At run time the images appear correctly in the view.

On a second view I have only 9 uiimageviews.  These uiimageviews will display up to nine of the images selected from the first view.  There are three images across and three images down.  The uiimageview at design time is the same size as on the first view.  The uiimageview image is assigned an image that is loaded into an array.   All the uiimageviews are sized the same and they also have the mode set to Aspect Fill. The images are assigned at run time using image1.image = xxx.  Where xxx is an image stored in an array.

However, on this second view, the images are not all the same size.  The height of the image changes dynamically.  The same image displayed in a different uiimageview on the view will be different sizes.  It is the height of the uiimageview that changes.  In some cases the image will fill the uiimageview differently.  It is like the mode changes dynamically.

I've tried using different modes and nothing changes.

Any ideas on what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

try resetting the frame of UIImageview's object  (of same size which you set at the design time) after setting its image property...

Comment: Hi,  Sorry about the delay in updating the status of this problem.  I was pulled into another project.  Anyway, resetting the frame did not help.  Anyway, I checked it after setting the image and it had not changed from design time.

Comment: hmm, seems like some specific issue, are you sure the uiimageview objects are properly created and disposed. may be due to previous values of frame its showing different size

Comment: I finally made some progress using this code.

imageNine.clipsToBounds = NO;
imageNine.contentMode=  UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
imageNine.image = [imagesChart objectAtIndex:selectedImage];